# how to add diagonal strokes to a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, cglayer

how can i add an X looking red stroke to a UIImageView.

i would like to add 2 diagonal red lines to a UIImageView, is there a way to do it programmatically using layers or masks? (not in drawRect)

Comment: Why not in drawRect which is where all drawing should be done?

Comment: Could you simply create another UIView at the same size and location of the one you wanted to add the red X over, have it draw the red X in it's drawRect (or just have it draw a scaled UIImage of a red X), and then make it visible and on top of your UIImageView?

Comment: @ericgorr uiimageview doesn't call drawRect, to answer your first comment

Comment: @ericgorr, i like your suggestion in your second comment, if you write it as an answer and throw a bit of the drawRect code i'll accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CAShapeLayer` with your X shape as its path. Depending on how you've drawn the path, you may want to set a `nil` fill colour (since a path just made of two crossed lines should not be filled).

Add the shape layer as a sublayer of your image view.